# how can we route traffic from all apps to SOCKS server on Android

Tags: android, server, socks

i have a socks proxy running on an app and i would like to route traffic from all applications on android through the socks server.How can we achieve this?

Comment: [How to set up a socks5 with Android cli?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/209505/218526)

Comment: [How to send all internet traffic to a SOCKS5 proxy server in local network?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/221448/218526)